# VB how to extract BRNumber, EnglishName, ChineseName from a string that is separated by space?

Tags: regex, vb.net, structure, uipath

[Gazette Document](https://www.gld.gov.hk/egazette/pdf/20242811/egn202428111399.pdf) ("The Government of the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region Gazette")

[image]

[image]

I'd like to extract the company information from the above PDF document. Due to the company's restrictions, I can only use Uipath's ReadPDF activity to extract the text in the PDF. I already dropped the head and tail and got all the company entries in the body. The structure of the company entry is as below,

BRNumber EnglishName ChineseName

The BRNumber could be a combination of letters and digits, which length is 8.
EnglishName could be a combination of letters and special characters.
ChineseName could be a combination of Chinese characters and special characters.

When either EnglishName or ChineseName is too long, it will be separated into 2 lines.

Either EnglishName or ChineseName can be empty.

BRNumber, EnglishName, ChineseName are separated by space. Words in EnglishName are also separated by space.

How can I extract BRNumber, EnglishName and ChineseName?

I tried to separate a single line with the regex
`([A-Za-z0-9\-]*)\s*(([A-Za-z0-9-'&.,\s()/]*)\s*([A-Za-z0-9-'&.,\s()/]*)\s*([A-Za-z0-9-'&.,\s()/]*))\s*([\d\u4e00-\u9fff-\s()（）]*)`
But when a ChineseName not start with Chinese character, the result is incorrect.

For example,

C1234567 | 20 Hello Co.Ltd | 20 你好有限公司

will become

C1234567 | 20 Hello Co.Ltd 20 | 你好有限公司

The bar is just for showing more clearly. Please ignore it.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the information described here: [Russian hacker group exploits Microsoft Windows feature in worldwide phishing attack](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/russian-hacker-group-exploits-microsoft-windows-feature-in-worldwide-phishing-attack/ar-BB1k5TEp?ocid=msedgdhp&pc=U531&cvid=8ddc204f2830417a9e9e550347396231&ei=206) it's unadvisable for anyone to open a PDF file from an unknown source.

Comment: This is a public Hong Kong government document. https://www.gld.gov.hk/egazette/pdf/20242811/egn202428111399.pdf

Comment: Can you get the data in a slightly different format? For example, if I open the PDF in SumatraPDF and copy-and-paste into a text editor, each element is on a separate line, e.g., `"12345678"<CRLF>"20 English Name"<CRLF>"Second line of English name"<CRLF>"First line of Chinese name"<CRLF>"Second line of Chinese name"`, which we could probably work with to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of RegEx, just use plain old string manipulation...

Search from the front for the first space to get BRNumber.
Search from the back for the last space to get ChineseName.
Everything in-between must be EnglishName.
Add an extra check for a multi-line string to handle the edge case.

Something like:

```
Public Class DataValues

    Public BRNumber As String
    Public EnglishName As String
    Public ChineseName As String

    Public Shared Function GetDataValues(ByVal data As String) As DataValues
        Dim dv As New DataValues
        Dim firstSpace As Integer = data.IndexOf(" ")
        Dim lastSpace As Integer = data.LastIndexOf(" ")
        Dim newLine As Integer = data.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)
        If newLine <> -1 AndAlso firstSpace <> -1 AndAlso firstSpace < newLine Then
            dv.BRNumber = data.Substring(0, firstSpace)
            dv.EnglishName = data.Substring(firstSpace + 1, newLine - firstSpace - 1)
            dv.ChineseName = data.Substring(newLine + Environment.NewLine.Length)
        ElseIf firstSpace <> -1 AndAlso lastSpace <> -1 AndAlso firstSpace <> lastSpace Then
            dv.BRNumber = data.Substring(0, firstSpace)
            dv.EnglishName = data.Substring(firstSpace + 1, lastSpace - firstSpace - 1)
            dv.ChineseName = data.Substring(lastSpace + 1)
        End If
        Return dv
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "BRNumber: " & BRNumber & Environment.NewLine &
            "EnglishName: " & EnglishName & Environment.NewLine &
            "ChineseName: " & ChineseName & Environment.NewLine
    End Function

End Class
```

Here's the class being used in a Button click event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim data As String = "C1234567 20 Hello Co.Ltd 20 你好有限公司"
    Dim data2 As String = "C1234567 20 Hello Co.Ltd 20" & Environment.NewLine & "你好有限公司"

    Dim dv1 As DataValues = DataValues.GetDataValues(data)
    Debug.Print(dv1.ToString())

    Dim dv2 As DataValues = DataValues.GetDataValues(data2)
    Debug.Print(dv2.ToString())
End Sub
```

Here's the output from the IDE:

```
BRNumber: C1234567
EnglishName: 20 Hello Co.Ltd 20
ChineseName: 你好有限公司

BRNumber: C1234567
EnglishName: 20 Hello Co.Ltd 20
ChineseName: 你好有限公司
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, either EnglishName or ChineseName can be empty. And the expected output would be BRNumber: C1234567 EnglishName: 20 Hello Co.Ltd ChineseName: 20 你好有限公司.

Comment: Tell us more about that `20` in there. Will there always be a number and a space before each name?

Comment: Not necessary to before each name. It's a rare case. Most of the ChineseName start with Chinese characters or the whole name is all Chinese characters. But there could be case that it contains special characters or numbers in it. 20 Hello Co.Ltd is just an example case. The space between 20 and Hello is not a must condition. It could be 20Hello Co.Ltd. Companies have diverse names in reality.

Comment: I've added a few examples in the picture. The first line, 72320767 C28A Limited 28香港有限公司. There is no space between 28 and 香港. The last line, 73450318 ENSO Jiu Jitsu Limited. There is no ChineseName.

Comment: Based on all of your comments, THERE IS NO RELIABLE WAY to differentiate between where the English name stops, and the Chinese name starts. The only cases where it's possible is where you said they are split into multiple lines. Otherwise, since there are regular characters and/or spaces in both names, you can't easily tell them apart!

Comment: I think you could reliably find the BRNumber, and then everything to the right of that.

Answer (score 0):

assuming this string:

```
    Dim sTest As String = "BRNumber EnglishName ChineseName"
    Dim sParts As String() = Split(sTest, " ")


    Debug.Print($"BRNumber = {sParts(0)}")
    Debug.Print($"English Name  = {sParts(1)}")
    Debug.Print($"Chinese name  = {sParts(2)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only RegEx then something like this should work:

```
(\d{8})\s((\d*)[A-Za-z-'&.,\s()/\d]{1,45})(?(?=\s\d{8})()|((?:\3)(?:(?:\s?)(?:[\u4e00-\u9fff()（）]+))))
```

You just need to adjust the value `{1,45}` to limit the maximum lenght of the EnglishName.

It is basically doing the work in four groups:

- Group 1 - **BRNumber** (Limited to 8 digits)
- Group 2 - **EnglishName** (Limited to 1 to 45 characters)
- Group 3 - Used to extract the numbers of the EnglishName
- Group 4 - **ChineseName** using result of Group 3 to include also the number.
  (Cases without ChineseName will not show anything under this group.